# Professor doesn't reply to email even after I talked to him

Tags: email, communication

A professor pitched his project that needs research assistants at an event in my department on Monday. I talked to him after the event about 5 five mins, telling him my background and that I am really interested. I sent him my CV after the event on Monday evening. Now that Tuesday has passed. I still didn't get any reply from the professor. What should I do now? Email him again or go to his office directly (now it is the exam period so he probably doesn't have office hours anymore)?

Comment: Why are you so impatient?  Do you think this person only has your email in his or her inbox?

Comment: Sorry it is just because I got ignored a few times by other professors during this semester.

Answer (score 4):

**Wait.** As Buffy said, a day is virtually no time at all. The professor may be trying to give others a chance to respond, or may just be busy with other things. While your zeal is admirable, overdoing it will raise red flags. If he invited applications on Monday, I would wait at least until Friday before following up. Depending on the local culture, dropping by his office in person on Friday (or the following week) may be a good idea; otherwise, I would (again on/after Friday) just send a *brief* e-mail saying that you are still interested and that you hope to discuss the position with him soon.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But do you think it is appropriate to just show up in his office on Friday (now that it is exam period, he doesn't hold his usual office hours (Mondays) anymore)?

Comment: I guess I am just nervous. Because I get ignored a few times by other professors this semester (like cold call). And now that he has a project that needs RAs. I think I should have a good shot.

Answer (score 1):

A day is no time at all during busy academic periods. But trying to find him is probably a good bet. Some things are best done face to face. He probably won't have made any decisions yet and a visit might help him decide.

But an immediate email probably won't get you anywhere.

Perhaps someone in the department office can set you up with an appointment.

But if a week passes and you haven't made contact, then email should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! So a follow up email restating my interest?

Comment: Also, is there a possibility that he missed my email? For example, he thought he would reply the next day but he ended up forgetting.